# Mirroring the Y axis of a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a 4x4 transformation matrix which represents a 3D transformation in a coordinate space where Y is down, but I need to apply the transformation matrix in a space where Y is up.  In order to accomplish this, I am attempting to mirror the transformation across the XZ plane, but I can not derive the appropriate operation to do this.

[image: Comparison of original and target axes]

My initial approach was to use a scale matrix with the $s_y$ component set to $-1$, where $A$ is the given matrix.

$$A_{out} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\times{}A$$

This did correctly mirror the translation component of the matrix, however the rotation component of the matrix becomes "corrupted" during this option, with multiple rotation axes being swapped, inverted, or scaled incorrectly.

I also attempted to manually adjust the matrix by multiplying $A_{24}$ by $-1$ which successfully mirrored the translation component, but I could not figure a matrix to flip the rotation.

Comment: For coordinate transformations of rotations you usually want something like $TAT^{-1}$. In this case your “scale” matrix is its own inverse; have you tried multiplying $A$ by that matrix on both the left **and** the right?

Comment: Using $4 \times 4$ matrices for representing 3D affine transforms (linear transformation L followed by a translation T) can be a slippery ground... In case of doubt, always come back to representation $X'=LX+T$ (with L a $3 \times 3$ matrix). The problem you meet is that you apply your transformation matrix M  (implicitly) in this way $X'=M(LX+T)$ whereas you intended to do $X'=MLX+T$.

Comment: @DavidK That worked, thanks!